# Achievability under arbitrary norm

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Assume we have some function that has an achievable upper bound given by a linear norm in a finite dimensional vector space. Can we state for sure that the bound is also achievable for the same vector space but equipped with arbitrary Lp-norm (Hölder's norm)?

Thank you for any hint!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean here. For starters, what is the domain and codomain of your function?

Comment: in the simplest case, I assume a single objective real-valued  function F(C, IICII), with known analytical expression.. Here C is n-dimensional (n is finite) real valued vector in a normed vector space, where IICII is a p-norm (i.e. the Hölder norm). And we are able to prove that F(C, IICII) is less than or equal to IICII for any C. So IICII is an upper bound.. We can also show that there exists a particular C* such that F(C*, IIC*II) equals to IIC*II, if IIC*II is either Chebyshev (Lmax) or linear norm  (L1)..

Comment: The question is the following: if there is any theretical result allowing us to claim that IICII is a attainable upper bound no matter what p-norm is used, i.e. the upper bound is  atainable for  all p,  and not only for p=1 (linear) or p=infinity (Chebushev)